# Avoiding Duplicates - Database Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have created a database with many tables but at the moment, i am concerned with 3 of the tables i have.  `Company table`, `Manager table`,`Customer table`.

Now every company has one manager to use the application so with that, it has a one to one relationship and the table looks like this

**Company**

name

email

phone

manager_id

**Manager**

id

name

But then, every company can have lots of customers and each customer can belong to more than one company. In respect to that, i made a many to many relationship with the manager table to create a pivot table.

Because i want to avoid duplication, in the customer table, phone is primary. Will this relationship avoid the duplication. I want to be sure of this before i start writing my codes..

I am a newbie with database design. Thank you

**Manger_has_customer**

manger_id

customer_id

PS: This is how the customer table looks like

**Customer**

id

name

phone

Comment: what kind of duplication that u want to avoid? u can have duplication handling when registering a customer into a database. by checking the customer name is existing or not.

Comment: @parkway  I want  the manager to avoid customer registering twice (duplicates) and now i want to know if my database structure does not break the rules.

Comment: your database table is good to go and customer ID should be unique identifier, And to helping in handling the duplicate, in your code you need to put a condition for checking the user is existing or not. U can check by customer name or check by customer email before insert into database. If existing, then prompt out dialog saying the customer is existing

Comment: This some sort of register handling..
`$sql=mysql_query("SELECT FROM customer(username, password, email) WHERE username=$fusername");
 if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
   {
    echo"name already exists";
   }
 else
    {
   //insert query goes here
    }`

Comment: Phone is a terrible candidate for primacy. Use a surrogate

Comment: @parkway please don't promote deprecated code

Comment: @Strawberry at least i have give some example for him. I didn't force him to use that code. I' just explain to him that he able to handle the duplicate by using handler condition before submit/insert into database.

Comment: @Strawberry, thank you very much but could you please explain why phone is terrible?

Comment: Phone numbers change

Comment: @Strawberry and so how can the surrogate replace phone for primacy?

Comment: @Strawberry and so how can the surrogate replace phone for primacy?

Comment: Typically, you'd just have an autoincrementing id as your PRIMARY KEY. phone would be UNIQUE

Comment: Alright. Thank you and if the database structure doesn't foul the rules, i guess i can go and use this database